# Program of symbolic algebra that allows to calculate derivatives.

Tags: derivatives, symbolic-computation

I am looking for some symbolic algebra program that allows me to calculate (for example) the $k-$th derivative a function of type $ f (t) = (1 + a (t))^{- 1} $ with $ a $ infinitely differentiable . It is so as not to have to calculate by hand $f ', f '', f'''$ etc.

For example, that the program literally gives me the following: $$f '(t) = - (1 + a (t))^{- 2} a'(t)$$
and so on.

Is there a program like that?
Thank you

Comment: In Maple, you can write diff(f(x),\$k). If $k$ is a constant, Maple will give you the answer. Sometimes, if $k$ is a variable Maple will calculate a formula for the $k$th derivative, for example if $f(x)=x^2 e^x$.

Comment: Even wolframalpha.com does it, it is online and free. Insert:  d/dx ((1+a(x))^(-1)) in the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can do this in Mathematica. When the "D" operator hits something about which it knows nothing, it just says something like
$$
D[a, t]
$$
to mean "derivative of $a$ with respect to $t$".